# Logstash, how to use grok patterns coming from event data

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have an ELK stack deployed on kubernetes used to collect containers' data. Among all the rest, it is using a grok filter to parse the actual log line based on a pattern.

My wish is to be able to setup this pattern by using an annotation in the kubernetes pod.

I added an annotation called `elk-grok-pattern` in the `pod`, configured `filebeat` in order to forward the annotation and I can get the annotation value as a field in my `event` in `logstash`, so far so good.

The problem is that I am unable to use the value of my field as a `grok pattern`.

The annotation in my pod looks like this:

```
Annotations:    elk-grok-pattern=%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:response_time}
```

The `filter` I am trying to use is similar to the following:

```
filter {
  # create a new field called "elk-grok-pattern" from the pod annotation
  mutate {
        rename => { "[kubernetes][annotations][elk-grok-pattern]" => "elk-grok-pattern" }
  }

  grok {
    pattern_definitions => {
      "CUSTOM" => "%{elk-grok-pattern}"
    }
    match => { "log" => "%{CUSTOM}" }
  }
}
```

Unluckily this leads to an error:

```
Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{elk-grok-pattern} not defined>
```

In practice, grok is interpreting my pattern literally, and not evaluating the string content coming from the event.

I also tried using the pattern directly, withoud defining a pattern_definition, like this:

```
grok {
  match => { "log" => "%{elk-grok-pattern}" }
}
```

But I get the same exact error.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal?
Any advice or possible workaround would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use this pattern in other places, why not just use it in the match like this?

```
grok {
  match => { "log" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:response_time}" }
}
```

If you want to use it later in other filters, check out this page on pattern creation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#setting_patterns_dir

Comment: Nope. The fact is that pattern is just an example. It will be different from pod to pod (and I'd like to be configured externally).
Otherwise, I would need to do an if-then-else pattern inside my filter to use the correct pattern for every pod.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523102/using-field-as-input-to-logstash-grok-filter-pattern